# Azure AADSTS900144: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_id'

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Getting the following error when pasting that link into a web browser in an attempt to login to my Azure app:

```
Microsoft
Sign in
Sorry, but we’re having trouble signing you in.

AADSTS900144: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_id'.
```

As you can see from the url below, client_id IS present (everything between<> are my own values..)

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<TENENT>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?response_type=id_token&state=<SOMESTATE>&client_id=<CLIENTID>&scope=<SCOPE>&redirect_uri=https://login.microsoftonline.com/<TENENT>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
```

The authorize endpoint receives query parameters, correct? Not sure why it is mentioning 'request body' as that is for POST requests from they way I understand things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameters should be in the body section and if they are not, this error might be thrown. Based on your description it sounds like that might be what is happening.

[image]

Comment: Interesting. Yeah, needs to be in body, not query params. the key/value format threw me a bit.

Comment: Where is the screenshot taken from on the azure portal? I am having the same issue

Comment: How do you include it though ? Please show an example.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify as I had difficulty setting the value.

[image]