# Microsoft Graph Authentication using O365 python lib

Tags: python-3.x, azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

I'm adpting a basic script, that i did to send standardized emails to a list of emails, to use msal.

I used the msal python lib (v 1.21.0) like so:

```
import msal

redirect_url = f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize/"

tokens_dir = r"<PATH>"
token_filename = r"<TOKEN_FILENAME>"
scopes = ["Mail.Send","Mail.ReadWrite","User.Read"]

authority = f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/"
app = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(client_id=client_id, client_credential=client_secret, authority=authority)

url = app.get_authorization_request_url(scopes=scopes, redirect_uri=redirect_url)

code = input("Token auth code:" )
app.acquire_token_by_authorization_code(code, scopes=scopes, redirect_uri=redirect_url)
```

For testing pourposes it's written on a ipython notebook. So I access the url given by the "get_authorization_request_url" method that was supposed to give me the authorization code.

But I'm getting this error `AADSTS900144: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_id'`. I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68838592/azure-aadsts900144-the-request-body-must-contain-the-following-parameter-client) talking about this, but I don't know how to include the parameter on the body instead of the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

I registered one Azure AD application and added `API permissions` as below:

[image]

In my case, I set `redirect_url` as https://jwt.ms for my application as below:

[image]

Now I ran **same code** in my Python notebook by modifying `redirect_url`  and printing `url` to get code like below:

```py
import msal

tenant_id = "3f5c7a77-062d-426c-8582-xxxxxxxxxxx"
client_id = "a26d7e57-0a26-4a0c-a756-xxxxxxxxxxx"
client_secret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
redirect_url = f"https://jwt.ms"

tokens_dir = r"<PATH>"
token_filename = r"<TOKEN_FILENAME>"
scopes = ["Mail.Send","Mail.ReadWrite","User.Read"]

authority = f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/"
app = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(client_id=client_id, client_credential=client_secret, authority=authority)

url = app.get_authorization_request_url(scopes=scopes, redirect_uri=redirect_url)

print(url)

code = input("Token auth code:" )
app.acquire_token_by_authorization_code(code, scopes=scopes, redirect_uri=redirect_url)
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I clicked on the URL from response, it opened new tab to **pick account** like below:

[image]

After signing in, I got the **consent screen** with permissions like this:

[image]

After accepting the above consent, it took me to `redirect_url` with **code** in address bar like below:

[image]

When I entered this code in `Token auth code:` I got tokens successfully in **response** like this:

[image]

Comment: Is ur application  multi or single tenant?

Comment: It's single tenant

Comment: As I saved my session and consent, I don't get those pages anymore. Instead the url takes me directly to the Error page with the cited error. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68838592/azure-aadsts900144-the-request-body-must-contain-the-following-parameter-clie) has a "solution" to this, but I don't know how to implement it

Comment: You have given authorize URL in `redirect_url`. Can you change it and try again?

Comment: I changed both in the script and the registered uri. I got an 404 error page.

Comment: I got the [same error](https://i.imgur.com/gmwodzV.png) when I gave authorize url in `redirect_url` like [this](https://i.imgur.com/tj1piuo.png). Can you include your error screenshot by editing your question?

Comment: Actually never mind, the change you suggested worked. As I was redacting the url from the 404 error page, I noticed that the code was given, so I used that url to fetch a token and it worked! Thanks