# Use Python to call SharePoint API get 401 response while I have the token

Tags: python, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, sharepoint-rest-api

I have registered my App in Azure with API permission as below:

[image]

Here is my python code.

```
import requests
from msal import ConfidentialClientApplication

client_id = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
client_secret = "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy"
tenant_id = "tttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt"
site_url = "https://{mytenent}.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite"
resource = "https://{mytenent}"

# Authenticate using client ID and secret
authority = f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}"
app = ConfidentialClientApplication(
    client_id=client_id,
    authority=authority,
    client_credential=client_secret,
)

scope=[resource + "/.default"]
token_response = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=scope)


access_token = token_response.get("access_token") #token_response["access_token"]
print(access_token)

endpoint_url = f"{site_url}/_api/web"
headers = {
    "Authorization": "Bearer " + access_token,
    "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
}
print(endpoint_url)
response = requests.get(endpoint_url, headers=headers)

# Check for errors in the SharePoint API response
if response.status_code == 200:
    data = response.json()
    print("SharePoint Site Title:", data["d"]["Title"])
else:
    print("SharePoint API Error:")
    print("Status Code:", response.status_code)
    print("Response:", response.text)
```

By the code print(access_token) I can get the token string so I think I do it right on get a token. But I got 401 response when calling SharePoint API.

> Status Code: 401 Response: {"error_description":"ID3035: The request
> was not valid or is malformed."}

What could be the problem? Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I registered one Entra ID application and granted **API permissions** as below:

[image]

Initially, I got **same error** when I ran your python code in my environment like this:

```py
import requests
from msal import ConfidentialClientApplication

client_id = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
client_secret = "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy"
tenant_id = "tttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt"
site_url = "https://{mytenent}.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite"
resource = "https://{mytenent}"

# Authenticate using client ID and secret
authority = f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}"
app = ConfidentialClientApplication(
    client_id=client_id,
    authority=authority,
    client_credential=client_secret,
)

scope=[resource + "/.default"]
token_response = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=scope)


access_token = token_response.get("access_token") #token_response["access_token"]
print(access_token)

endpoint_url = f"{site_url}/_api/web"
headers = {
    "Authorization": "Bearer " + access_token,
    "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
}
print(endpoint_url)
response = requests.get(endpoint_url, headers=headers)

# Check for errors in the SharePoint API response
if response.status_code == 200:
    data = response.json()
    print("SharePoint Site Title:", data["d"]["Title"])
else:
    print("SharePoint API Error:")
    print("Status Code:", response.status_code)
    print("Response:", response.text)
```

**Response:**

[image]

> To resolve the error, you can switch to **delegated** flows like interactive flow, authorization code flow etc.. for generating token as you granted permissions of **Delegated** type.

In my case, I ran below modified code that uses **interactive flow** for generating token and got **response** successfully like this:

```py
import requests
import msal

client_id = "appId"
tenant_id = "tenantId"
site_url = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/sridemosite"
resource = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com"

# Authenticate using client ID and secret
authority = f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}"

app = msal.PublicClientApplication(
    client_id,
    authority=authority,
)
scope=[resource + "/.default"]
token_response = app.acquire_token_interactive(scopes=scope)
access_token = token_response['access_token']
print(access_token)

endpoint_url = f"{site_url}/_api/web"
headers = {
    "Authorization": "Bearer " + access_token,
    "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
}
print()
print(endpoint_url)
response = requests.get(endpoint_url, headers=headers)

# Check for errors in the SharePoint API response
if response.status_code == 200:
    data = response.json()
    print("SharePoint Site Title:", data["d"]["Title"])
else:
    print("SharePoint API Error:")
    print("Status Code:", response.status_code)
    print("Response:", response.text)
```

**Response:**

[image]

Make sure to enable **public client** flow and add redirect URI in *Mobile and desktop applications* platform while using **interactive flow**:

[image]

Alternatively, you can also generate access token using **client certificate** by granting permissions of **Application** type, refer below blog:

[Getting an App Only access token for SharePoint REST APIs by **Martin Loitzl**](https://blog.loitzl.com/posts/getting-an-app-only-access-token-for-sharepoint-rest-apis/)

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I have also checked your answer on another thread (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76238010/azure-request-to-api-endpoint-returns-401-unauthorized-when-given-an-access-toke). I successfully get SharePoint data using grant_type:authorization_code. However I need to put my script on pipeline to run automatically so user cannot be attended. Is using Client Cert the only way to make it work?

Comment: If you don't want user interaction, the only way is to use client certificate authentication by granting permissions of **Application** type. You can also use _username password_ flow but that is not recommended as you need to pass user's password. If you are okay to use username password flow, check this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77153291/how-to-avoid-pop-up-tag-in-browser-while-getting-access-token-with-using-msal-in/77221863#77221863

Comment: @Sridevi our tenant have enabled conditional access policy, login of azure AD require input OTP thru MS Auth App. If so username password flow will not be sufficient in this case?

Comment: Yes, If MFA is enabled you cannot use username password flow. The only way is to use client certificate authentication in your scenario.