Trying to Authenticate with SharePoint and get list of files via API using access token
I'm trying to follow documentation and read files from SharePoint using APIs.
I have a client_id+client_secret and I'm able to retrieve an access token like so:

I then try to use this token and calling GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl:

I get a 401 (Unauthorized) error: ID3035: The request was not valid or is malformed.
I'm not entirely familiar with SharePoint so not even sure 'AAA' is considered a folder. It's a document library from which I want to access the content of "Monthly reports" folder.

Any help would be appreciated.

Which permissions have you granted in Entra portal during app registration?

@user2250152 - I'm not entirely sure as someone created the app for me. I will check. Does it seem like an issue with permissions? If so - which ones should I ask for to be able to perform download of files from a specific folder in a specific site?

The error usually occurs if you grant permissions of Delegated type but using client credentials flow to generate token. To resolve the error, generate the token with Delegated flow like authorization code flow. Refer this similar thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77832417/use-python-to-call-sharepoint-api-get-401-response-while-i-have-the-token?rq=2

I created one document library named AAA in Finance SharePoint site with one folder like this:

I registered one Entra ID application and granted API permissions of Delegated type as below:

Now, I generated access token using client credentials flow via Postman as below:
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type:client_credentials
client_id:appID
client_secret:secret
scope: https://tenant.sharepoint.com/.default

Response:

When I used this token to call SharePoint REST API, I too got same error as below:
GET https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/Finance1/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('AAA')

Response:

To resolve this, generate access token using delegated flow like authorization code as we granted permissions of Delegated type in app registration.
Initially, I got the code value by running below authorization URL in browser:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
?client_id=appID
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&scope=https://tenant.sharepoint.com/.default
&state=12345


Now, I used this code to generate access token with authorization code flow via Postman:
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type:authorization_code
client_id:appID
client_secret:secret
scope: https://tenant.sharepoint.com/.default
code:code
redirect_uri: https://jwt.ms

Response:

When I used this token to call SharePoint REST API, I got the response successfully like this:
GET https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/Finance1/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('AAA')

Response:

To retrieve the files present in that folder, you can use below SharePoint REST API call:
GET https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/Finance/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('AAA/Monthly Reports')/Files

Response:

You can also use Microsoft Graph API to download SharePoint files via REST API.
Reference:
azure - Download File from Secure Sharepoint using Rest API - AudienceUriValidationFailedException - Stack Overflow

I apologize for the late reply, took me awhile to get around to try it.

Trying to do these requests in Postman are my first step. I would later need to write a Python script that executes this flow.
However, seeing as my organization defined an SSO for signing in I think I won't be able to automate the flow completely.
I'm considering using Application permission.

In that case, make use of Microsoft Graph API by granting Application permissions. Check the reference link I mentioned in answer or post a new question with more details and share link here
