# AzureAD configuration with public key authentication on Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure, azure-active-directory

I successfully set up a sample application to utilize AzureAD for user authentication following the steps outlined in [this blog post](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-azuread-authenticate-users). The post provides instructions on configuring AzureAD and the application's identity using client-id and client-secret for the application configuration, and the setup working properly.

However I try to configure AzureAD and application’s identity using with public key I could not able to successfully setup.

I used following openssl commands to generate the public key.

> $certname = "AzureCertificate"
>
> $cert = New-SelfSignedCertificate -Subject "CN=$certname"
> -CertStoreLocation "Cert:\CurrentUser\My" -KeyExportPolicy Exportable -KeySpec Signature -KeyLength 2048 -KeyAlgorithm RSA -HashAlgorithm SHA256
>
> Export-Certificate -Cert $cert -FilePath
> "C:\Personal\Work1\AZURE\KEY$certname.cer"

[image]

Then I generated the public key using following command in command line

> openssl x509 -inform der -in AzureCertificate.cer -pubkey -noout >
> your-public-key.pem

Then I uploaded the generated certificate AzureCertificate.cer file in to the AzurePortal application as show below.

[image]

Then I have configured the certificate location on the applciation.yml as show below and added publicKey.pem file in to resources folder. Please note I have replace correct **my-tenant-id and my-client-id** in applciation.yml file.

[image]

Then I have run the application It first correctly redirecting to Microsoft login page and then after user enters the credentials system giving error message as below.

[invalid_request] AADSTS900144: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_id'. Trace ID: yyyyyyy Correlation ID: xxxxxxx Timestamp: 2023-11-18 15:14:37Z

[image]

Highly appreciated if someone share your experiencing this configuration process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#second-case-access-token-request-with-a-certificate) describes the necessary information that should be provided in order to perform an access token request with a certificate.

You need to perform a HTTP request like the following:

```
POST /{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token HTTP/1.1               // Line breaks for clarity
Host: login.microsoftonline.com:443
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default
&client_id=97e0a5b7-d745-40b6-94fe-5f77d35c6e05
&client_assertion_type=urn%3Aietf%3Aparams%3Aoauth%3Aclient-assertion-type%3Ajwt-bearer
&client_assertion=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6Imd4OHRHeXN5amNScUtqRlBuZDdSRnd2d1pJMCJ9.eyJ{a lot of characters here}M8U3bSUKKJDEg
&grant_type=client_credentials
```

In addition to the Entra ID tenant and the app client id, you need to indicate the client assertion type, it is a constant value, and a client assertion.

The client assertion is a JSON web token created and signed with the certificate registered as credentials for the application in the Azure Portal.

The characteristics of this JSON web token are described in detail [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/certificate-credentials).

Using this type of authentication mechanism with Spring Boot is not obvious but fortunately you can find different examples that exemplifies how to that.

Consider for instance [this excellent one](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-spring-boot-samples/tree/main/aad/spring-security/servlet/oauth2/login-authenticate-using-private-key-jwt) provided as part of the azure samples repository in Github.

Basically, it defines a set of [helper classes](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-spring-boot-samples/tree/main/aad/spring-security/servlet/oauth2/login-authenticate-using-private-key-jwt/src/main/java/com/azure/spring/sample/reactive/servlet/oauth2/login/jwt/azure/activedirectory), especially [one](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-spring-boot-samples/blob/main/aad/spring-security/servlet/oauth2/login-authenticate-using-private-key-jwt/src/main/java/com/azure/spring/sample/reactive/servlet/oauth2/login/jwt/azure/activedirectory/AzureActiveDirectoryJwtClientAuthenticationParametersConverter.java) defined in order to provide the `client_assertion` and `client_assertion_type` parameters when performing the request:

```java
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.endpoint.AbstractOAuth2AuthorizationGrantRequest;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistration;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.ClientAuthenticationMethod;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.endpoint.OAuth2ParameterNames;
import org.springframework.util.Assert;
import org.springframework.util.LinkedMultiValueMap;
import org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap;

import java.util.Map;

public class AzureActiveDirectoryJwtClientAuthenticationParametersConverter<T extends AbstractOAuth2AuthorizationGrantRequest>
    implements Converter<T, MultiValueMap<String, String>> {

    private final static Logger LOGGER =
        LoggerFactory.getLogger(AzureActiveDirectoryJwtClientAuthenticationParametersConverter.class);
    private static final String CLIENT_ASSERTION_TYPE_VALUE = "urn:ietf:params:oauth:client-assertion-type:jwt-bearer";

    private final Map<String, AzureActiveDirectoryCertificateSignedJwtAssertionFactory> factories;

    public AzureActiveDirectoryJwtClientAuthenticationParametersConverter(
        Map<String, AzureActiveDirectoryCertificateSignedJwtAssertionFactory> factories) {
        this.factories = factories;
    }

    @Override
    public MultiValueMap<String, String> convert(T authorizationGrantRequest) {
        Assert.notNull(authorizationGrantRequest, "authorizationGrantRequest cannot be null");

        ClientRegistration registration = authorizationGrantRequest.getClientRegistration();
        ClientAuthenticationMethod method = registration.getClientAuthenticationMethod();
        if (!ClientAuthenticationMethod.PRIVATE_KEY_JWT.equals(registration.getClientAuthenticationMethod())) {
            return null;
        }

        try {
            return createParameters(registration);
        } catch (AzureActiveDirectoryAssertionException exception) {
            LOGGER.error("Failed to create parameters.", exception);
        }
        return null;
    }

    private MultiValueMap<String, String> createParameters(ClientRegistration registration) throws AzureActiveDirectoryAssertionException {
        MultiValueMap<String, String> parameters = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        parameters.set(OAuth2ParameterNames.CLIENT_ASSERTION_TYPE, CLIENT_ASSERTION_TYPE_VALUE);
        parameters.set(OAuth2ParameterNames.CLIENT_ASSERTION, createAssertion(registration));
        return parameters;
    }

    private String createAssertion(ClientRegistration registration) throws AzureActiveDirectoryAssertionException {
        return factories.get(registration.getRegistrationId()).createJwtAssertion();
    }
}
```

and [another one](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-spring-boot-samples/blob/main/aad/spring-security/servlet/oauth2/login-authenticate-using-private-key-jwt/src/main/java/com/azure/spring/sample/reactive/servlet/oauth2/login/jwt/azure/activedirectory/AzureActiveDirectoryCertificateSignedJwtAssertionFactory.java) used to generate the appropriate JWT web token:

```java
import com.nimbusds.jose.JOSEException;
import com.nimbusds.jose.JOSEObjectType;
import com.nimbusds.jose.JWSAlgorithm;
import com.nimbusds.jose.JWSHeader;
import com.nimbusds.jose.JWSSigner;
import com.nimbusds.jose.crypto.factories.DefaultJWSSignerFactory;
import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.JWK;
import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.RSAKey;
import com.nimbusds.jose.util.Base64URL;
import com.nimbusds.jwt.JWTClaimsSet;
import com.nimbusds.jwt.SignedJWT;
import org.springframework.util.Assert;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateEncodingException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPublicKey;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.UUID;

/**
 * A factory used to create Microsoft Entra JWT assertion signed with a certificate.
 *
 * @author Rujun Chen
 * @see <a href="https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-certificate-credentials">
 * Certificate credentials</a>
 * @since 2022-02-18
 */
public class AzureActiveDirectoryCertificateSignedJwtAssertionFactory {

    private final JWSSigner signer;
    private final JWSHeader header;
    private final JWTClaimsSet templateClaims;

    /**
     * @param file Path of certificate file. The file should contain encrypted private key and certificate.
     * And the file name should have ".pfx" as suffix.
     * @param password The password of the encrypted private key in certificate file.
     * @throws AzureActiveDirectoryAssertionException if failed to create factory.
     */
    public AzureActiveDirectoryCertificateSignedJwtAssertionFactory(String file, String password, String tenantId,
                                                                    String clientId) throws AzureActiveDirectoryAssertionException {
        try {
            String fileExtension = file.substring(file.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
            Assert.isTrue("pfx".equals(fileExtension), "Only support file with '.pfx' extension.");
            KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
            keyStore.load(new FileInputStream(file), password.toCharArray());
            String alias = keyStore.aliases().nextElement();
            PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey) keyStore.getKey(alias, password.toCharArray());
            X509Certificate x509Certificate = (X509Certificate) keyStore.getCertificate(alias);
            PublicKey publicKey = x509Certificate.getPublicKey();
            signer = createJWSSigner(publicKey, privateKey);
            header = createJWSHeader(x509Certificate);
            templateClaims = createTemplateJWTClaims(tenantId, clientId);
        } catch (KeyStoreException | IOException | CertificateException | NoSuchAlgorithmException |
            UnrecoverableKeyException | JOSEException exception) {
            throw new AzureActiveDirectoryAssertionException("Failed to create factory.", exception);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create JWT assertion
     *
     * @throws AzureActiveDirectoryAssertionException If failed to create assertion.
     */
    public String createJwtAssertion() throws AzureActiveDirectoryAssertionException {
        JWTClaimsSet claims = createJWTClaimsSet();
        SignedJWT signedJwt = new SignedJWT(header, claims);
        try {
            signedJwt.sign(signer);
        } catch (JOSEException exception) {
            throw new AzureActiveDirectoryAssertionException("Failed to sign JWT.", exception);
        }
        return signedJwt.serialize();
    }

    private JWSSigner createJWSSigner(PublicKey publicKey, PrivateKey privateKey) throws JOSEException {
        // Microsoft Entra ID currently supports only RSA.
        // Refs: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-self-signed-certificate
        JWK jwk = new RSAKey.Builder((RSAPublicKey) publicKey)
            .privateKey(privateKey)
            .keyID(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
            .build();
        return new DefaultJWSSignerFactory().createJWSSigner(jwk);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private JWSHeader createJWSHeader(X509Certificate x509Certificate) throws CertificateEncodingException,
        NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        return new JWSHeader.Builder(JWSAlgorithm.RS256)
            .type(JOSEObjectType.JWT)
            .x509CertThumbprint(Base64URL.encode(getX5t(x509Certificate)))
            .build();
    }

    private byte[] getX5t(X509Certificate cert)
        throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateEncodingException {
        MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
        byte[] der = cert.getEncoded();
        digest.update(der);
        return digest.digest();
    }

    private JWTClaimsSet createTemplateJWTClaims(String tenantId, String clientId) {
        return new JWTClaimsSet.Builder()
            .audience(String.format("https://login.microsoftonline.com/%s/v2.0", tenantId))
            .issuer(clientId)
            .subject(clientId)
            .build();
    }

    private JWTClaimsSet createJWTClaimsSet() {
        Date currentTime = new Date();
        return new JWTClaimsSet.Builder(templateClaims)
            .expirationTime(Date.from(currentTime.toInstant().plusSeconds(300))) // 5 minutes after currentTime.
            .jwtID(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
            .notBeforeTime(currentTime)
            .issueTime(currentTime)
            .build();
    }


}
```

[This configuration class](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-spring-boot-samples/blob/main/aad/spring-security/servlet/oauth2/login-authenticate-using-private-key-jwt/src/main/java/com/azure/spring/sample/reactive/servlet/oauth2/login/jwt/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.java) glues everything together:

```java
import com.azure.spring.sample.reactive.servlet.oauth2.login.jwt.azure.activedirectory.AzureActiveDirectoryAssertionException;
import com.azure.spring.sample.reactive.servlet.oauth2.login.jwt.azure.activedirectory.AzureActiveDirectoryCertificateSignedJwtAssertionFactory;
import com.azure.spring.sample.reactive.servlet.oauth2.login.jwt.azure.activedirectory.AzureActiveDirectoryJwtClientAuthenticationParametersConverter;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.endpoint.DefaultAuthorizationCodeTokenResponseClient;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.endpoint.OAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantRequestEntityConverter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistration;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistrationRepository;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private static final Pattern ISSUER_URI_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("https://login.microsoftonline.com/(.*?)/v2.0");

    private final Environment environment;
    private final ClientRegistrationRepository repository;

    public WebSecurityConfiguration(Environment environment, ClientRegistrationRepository repository) {
        this.environment = environment;
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http.oauth2Login()
                .tokenEndpoint()
                  // Please, note the name of the client provided, 
                  // as we will see it will match the one in the configuration
                    .accessTokenResponseClient(accessTokenResponseClient(Collections.singletonList("client-1"), repository))
                    .and()
                .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
        // @formatter:off
    }

    private DefaultAuthorizationCodeTokenResponseClient accessTokenResponseClient(
        List<String> registrationIds, ClientRegistrationRepository repository
    ) throws AzureActiveDirectoryAssertionException {
        OAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantRequestEntityConverter converter =
            new OAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantRequestEntityConverter();
        converter.addParametersConverter(
            new AzureActiveDirectoryJwtClientAuthenticationParametersConverter<>(createFactoryMap(registrationIds, repository)));
        DefaultAuthorizationCodeTokenResponseClient client = new DefaultAuthorizationCodeTokenResponseClient();
        client.setRequestEntityConverter(converter);
        return client;
    }

    private Map<String, AzureActiveDirectoryCertificateSignedJwtAssertionFactory> createFactoryMap(
        List<String> registrationIds, ClientRegistrationRepository repository
    ) throws AzureActiveDirectoryAssertionException {
        Map<String, AzureActiveDirectoryCertificateSignedJwtAssertionFactory> factories = new HashMap<>();
        for (String registrationId: registrationIds) {
            AzureActiveDirectoryCertificateSignedJwtAssertionFactory factory = createFactory(registrationId, repository);
            if (factory != null) {
                factories.put(registrationId, factory);
            }
        }
        return factories;
    }

    private AzureActiveDirectoryCertificateSignedJwtAssertionFactory createFactory(
        String registrationId, ClientRegistrationRepository repository
    ) throws AzureActiveDirectoryAssertionException {
        String clientCertificatePath = environment.getProperty(
            String.format("spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.%s.client-certificate-path", registrationId));
        if (!StringUtils.hasText(clientCertificatePath)) {
            return null;
        }
        String clientCertificatePassword = environment.getProperty(
            String.format("spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.%s.client-certificate-password", registrationId));
        if (!StringUtils.hasText(clientCertificatePassword)) {
            return null;
        }
        ClientRegistration registration = repository.findByRegistrationId(registrationId);
        String tenantId = getTenantIdFromIssuerUri(registration.getProviderDetails().getIssuerUri());
        String clientId = registration.getClientId();
        return new AzureActiveDirectoryCertificateSignedJwtAssertionFactory(
            clientCertificatePath, clientCertificatePassword, tenantId, clientId);
    }

    static String getTenantIdFromIssuerUri(String issuerUri) {
        Matcher matcher = ISSUER_URI_PATTERN.matcher(issuerUri);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            return matcher.group(1);
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Please, pay especial attention to the `accessTokenResponseClient` method.

Finally, [this](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-spring-boot-samples/blob/main/aad/spring-security/servlet/oauth2/login-authenticate-using-private-key-jwt/src/main/resources/application.yml) is the relevant configuration:

```yaml
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        provider: # Refs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#oauth2login-common-oauth2-provider
          azure-active-directory:
            issuer-uri: https://login.microsoftonline.com/${tenant-id}/v2.0 # Refs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#webflux-oauth2-login-openid-provider-configuration
        registration:
          client-1:
            provider: azure-active-directory
            client-id: ${client-1-client-id}
            client-authentication-method: private_key_jwt
            client-certificate-path: ${client-1-certificate-path}
            client-certificate-password: ${client-1-certificate-password}
            scope: openid, profile
            redirect-uri: http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/
```

Please, don't forget to set the appropriate value for the different placeholders defined in the above configuration.

Comment: @casper The fact that the bounty ended is not important: please, if you have a chance, test the linked example code: I tested myself and it works perfectly. I hope it would be of help to you as well.

Comment: I managed to follow these instructions and able to authenticate application using the certificate. Would like to check whether there is a way to replace the client-certificate-password with private key ?

Comment: I am happy to hear that in the end you managed to access Azure AD using the proposed solution. Please, I don't fully understand your question: do you mean using something like `key-set-uri` as in your original solution?

Answer (score 1):

You have followed the steps to generate a certificate, uploaded it to Azure, and configured your `application.yml` with the public key, but you are receiving an error stating that the 'client_id' parameter is missing.

From the error message in the last screenshot, it seems that the AzureAD authentication process is not receiving the `client_id` parameter as part of the request, as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69393785/6309) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72572698/6309).

From your `application.yml`, I have a few suggestions:

- The `provider` under `registration` should match the name of the provider under `provider`. In your configuration, the provider is named `azure` in both sections, which is correct. But make sure this consistency is maintained throughout the application.
- The scopes specified under `registration` are typically correct for OpenID Connect (`openid`, `email`, `profile`). Check that the scopes align with what your application requires and what Azure AD is configured to allow.
- The `jwt.key-set-uri` under `provider` should be unnecessary in the context of client authentication using `private_key_jwt`. That setting is typically used by resource servers to validate JWTs, not by clients to authenticate to the authorization server.
- If using `private_key_jwt` for authentication, the `client-secret` should not be present, as this authentication method uses a private key instead of a client secret. (as confirmed in "[How to Get an Azure Access Token Using Self-signed Certificate with Spring Boot](https://medium.com/codex/how-to-get-an-azure-access-token-using-self-signed-certificate-with-spring-boot-140dac047454)" from [Milos Zivkovic](https://medium.com/@zivce/about))
- The Baeldung guide mentions setting up redirection URIs for the authorization code flow, but this is not directly represented in the `application.yml`. If using the authorization code flow, make sure the redirect URIs are correctly configured in the Azure AD application registration and, if necessary, specified in your Spring Security configuration.

  ```yaml
  # This is an optional setting depending on your setup
  registration:
     azure-dev:
       redirect-uri: "{baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}"
  ```
- Make sure the URLs for `issuer-uri` and `jwk-set-uri` are correctly typed and match your Azure AD configuration. Typographical errors in URLs can lead to failures in fetching the necessary metadata and keys.
- If you are using `private_key_jwt`, make sure Azure AD is configured to accept a JWT signed with your private key as a means of client authentication.
- Depending on the OAuth flow you are using (e.g., authorization code vs. client credentials), make sure the `authorization-grant-type` is correctly specified in the `registration` section. That is not included in the provided configuration but is necessary for some OAuth flows.

  ```yaml
  registration:
     azure-dev:
       authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
       # Use "client_credentials" for service-to-service communication
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Since your error message complains about not having `client-id` in request body, I'd suggest you to set the `client-authentication-method` parameter (next to the `client-id` property) in your `application.yml` file to `client_secret_post`.

By looking at `org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.endpoint.OAuth2ClientCredentialsGrantRequestEntityConverter.createParameters(OAuth2ClientCredentialsGrantRequest)` method, by setting this parameter, it'll send the client_id in request body

```java
    @Override
    protected MultiValueMap<String, String> createParameters(
            OAuth2ClientCredentialsGrantRequest clientCredentialsGrantRequest) {
        ClientRegistration clientRegistration = clientCredentialsGrantRequest.getClientRegistration();
        MultiValueMap<String, String> parameters = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        parameters.add(OAuth2ParameterNames.GRANT_TYPE, clientCredentialsGrantRequest.getGrantType().getValue());
        if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(clientRegistration.getScopes())) {
            parameters.add(OAuth2ParameterNames.SCOPE,
                    StringUtils.collectionToDelimitedString(clientRegistration.getScopes(), " "));
        }
        
        // HERE IS THE SPRING MAGIC :)
        if (ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_POST.equals(clientRegistration.getClientAuthenticationMethod())) {
            parameters.add(OAuth2ParameterNames.CLIENT_ID, clientRegistration.getClientId());
            parameters.add(OAuth2ParameterNames.CLIENT_SECRET, clientRegistration.getClientSecret());
        }
        return parameters;
    }
```

Same logic applies to other related classes :

- `org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.endpoint.OAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantRequestEntityConverter`
- `org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.endpoint.OAuth2PasswordGrantRequestEntityConverter`
- `org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.endpoint.OAuth2RefreshTokenGrantRequestEntityConverter`

Hope it'll solve your problem